# normal distribution derivation

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

In this derivation:

http://www.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/Papers/Normal/default.html

how do these equal?
$$ -k\int (x-\mu) dx = -\frac{k}{2} (x-\mu)^2$$

Isn't this the case?

$$ -k\int (x-\mu) dx = -\frac{kx^2}{2} + k\mu x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given comes from **one** antiderivative of $x-\mu$.  Your answer comes from **another** antiderivative of $x-\mu$. The two differ by a constant, so both of them are correct antiderivatives. Neither of them is the general antiderivative of $x-\mu$.

The **general** antiderivative of $x-\mu$ can be written as $\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2+C$ or as $\frac{x^2}{2}-\mu x+C$, where in each case the $C$ is an arbitrary constant of integration. Your source presumably found the first form more convenient.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understood it (constants C for both antiderivatives you provided can be matched to make them equal to each other)

Comment: You are welcome. This is an issue that comes up most often when one integrates trigonometric functions. Because of the many "trig identities" there are many combinations of them that differ by a constant, but look very different.